# Открываю файл разными редакторами — содержимое разное. Почему?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, sublime-text

Есть mkv файл. Если открываю через блокнот или в бинарном режиме в visual studio, то получаю набор символов вида "→EЯ??B┼?☺Bт?♦BуB'?matroskaB╪?☺". Но случайно открыл в sublime text, так там сразу получился идеальный (для дальнейшей обработки) результат - набор шестнадцатеричных чисел (на всякий случай часть из них - 1a45 dfa3 0100 0000).

Казалось бы, достаточно преобразовать эти символы в VS в двоичный код и результат будет таким же. Только при преобразовании символов в int (и uint32_t) происходят косяки. А именно - уже третий и четвёртый символы, описанной выше последовательности, преобразовываются в отрицательные числа (в случае uint в многозначное положительное), в результате чего и двоичный код выходит неправильный.
Почему так? Как мне получить в VS нормальную последовательность чисел?
[![Тут результат преобразования этих символов сначала в int, а потом в двоичный код.
После слова Тест идёт два числа - это я перевёл шестнадцатеричные числа, полученные из sublime text, в двоичный код. 
Если не считать первые 8 нулей (откуда они могут браться, если в другом редакторе их нет?) в последовательности, полученной в VS, а так же неверно переведённых символов, то числа совпадают. ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8J5i.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8J5i.jpg)

И вот код, которым открываю файл и провожу преобразование.

```
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
  string path = "video.mkv";

  ifstream mkv;

  mkv.open(path, fstream::binary);

  if (!mkv.is_open())
  {
    cout << "Not" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "Success!" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      char byte;
      mkv >> byte;
      cout << byte << "\t" << (int)byte << "\t" << bitset<16>((int)byte) << "\t" << i << endl;
    }
    cout << "Test: " << bitset<16>(0x1a45) << "\t" << bitset<16>(0xdfa3) << endl;
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Но char - знаковый. От -128 до 127 вроде, unsigned char - беззнаковый (от 0 до 255). И используйте static_cast вместо сишного стиля приведения типов, вы же на С++ пишите, не на Си. Я не пользовался VS, не знаю ничего про наличие там режима hex-редактора. Поставьте любой hex-редактор и в нём просматривайте бинарные файлы (sublime-text судя по вашим словами умеет в hex режим, почему так важно открыть mkv именно в VS??)

Comment: @vegorov Причина весьма стыдная - не удалось подружиться с другими средами. В том плане, что компилируя в том же Sublime Text выдаёт лишь сообщение об отсутствии ошибок, но без выполнения программы. Я самоучка, поэтому так. И, насколько я понимаю, данное задание должно выполняться в любой среде, значит и VS подойдёт. Мне скорее нужна последовательность двоичная, нежели hex редактор.

Comment: Причём тут компиляция, запуск и прочее, если вы просто хотите посмотреть из чего состоит файл в hex режиме? Вы же этот mkv файл не компилируете? Вы его просто открыть пытались в hex режиме. А компилируете вы программу на С++, которая читает вам тот же файл mkv и выводит его побайтово. Чем пользоваться, чтобы сравнить результат работы программы и содержимое файла mkv, по-моему, не должно играть большого значения

Comment: @vegorov В общем, вся проблема была именно в том, что использовал обычный char. А остальное само собой решилось. Благодарю за помощь.